# Extjs treepanel store.load() issue

Tags: json, extjs, treegrid, extjs5

I have found many examples of tree that have been loaded via root data in store which is static or via tree store that loads data tree view appears, ultimately loading the tree in advance.

My requirement is the tree is initially empty, with no data so I use removeAll on the tree store to achieve it even if the tee is initially loaded.

I am using ExtJs V 5.0.1.

Next on lick of button I load the tree via store.load method.

The tree data kept in json file outputted by php rest service.

The tree loads fine with the button click. **The issue is all the collapse or expand event only works ones. That in my case the first element is expanded will collapse once and then wont expand. Similarly for the collapsed child element, wont collapse once expanded.**

Adding my code below

```
Ext.define('TestTheme2.controller.Controller', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

requires: [
    'Ext.window.MessageBox'
],

stores: [

],

config: {
    isGridInspected: false
},

refs: {
    treeGrid: '#treegrid'
},

control: {        

    "#treegrid":{
        afterrender: 'afterViewRender'
    },
    "#loadButton":{

        click:'onBtnClick'
    }


},   

afterViewRender: function(component, eOpts){
    this.getTreeGrid().getStore().removeAll();
},

onBtnClick: function(){
    this.getTreeGrid().getStore().load();
}
```

});

My view code

```
Ext.define('TestTheme2.view.MyTreeGrid', {
extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
alias: 'widget.MyTreeGrid',


requires: [
    'TestTheme2.store.MyStore',
    'Ext.tree.View',
    'Ext.grid.column.Check',
    'Ext.tree.Column',
    'Ext.grid.column.Widget',
    'Ext.button.Button',
    'Ext.menu.Menu',
    'Ext.menu.Item',
    'Ext.data.*',
    'Ext.grid.*',
    'Ext.tree.*',
],


itemId: 'treegrid',
width: '',
title: '',
allowDeselect: true,
enableColumnHide: false,
rowLines: true,
scroll: 'vertical',
sortableColumns: false,
store: 'MyStore',
rootVisible: false,

viewConfig: {
    itemId: 'mytreeview2',
    enableTextSelection: false,
    markDirty: false,
    stripeRows: true,
    animate: true
},
columns: [
    {
        xtype: 'checkcolumn',
        itemId: 'mycheck',
        width: 50,
        sortable: false,
        dataIndex: 'mark',
        text: ''
    },
    {
        xtype: 'treecolumn',
        width: 120,
        sortable: false,
        dataIndex: 'year',
        text: 'Year',
        flex: 1
    },
    {
        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
        width: 120,
        sortable: false,
        dataIndex: 'week',
        text: 'Week'
    },
    {
        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
        width: 110,
        sortable: false,
        dataIndex: 'startdate',
        text: 'Start Date'
    },
    {
        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
        width: 110,
        sortable: false,
        dataIndex: 'enddate',
        text: 'End Date'
    }
]
```

});

My Store Code

```
Ext.define('TestTheme2.store.MyStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',

requires: [
    'TestTheme2.model.MyModel'
],

constructor: function(cfg) {
    var me = this;
    cfg = cfg || {};
    me.callParent([Ext.apply({
        storeId: 'MyStore',
        model: 'TestTheme2.model.MyModel',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '../../PhpWS/MockRestFlow?Service=MyService&type=byweek'               
        }
    }, cfg)]);
}
```

});

My Model code

```
Ext.define('TestTheme2.model.MyModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

requires: [
    'Ext.data.field.Field'
],

fields: [        
    {
        name: 'year'
    },
    {
        name: 'week'
    }
    {
        name: 'startdate'
    },
    {
        name: 'enddate'
    }
    {
        name: 'mark'
    }

]
```

});

My Json File

```
{
            text: '.',
            children: [
                {
                    year: 2014,
                    week: 33,
                    synergyid: '',
                    startdate: '01/11/2014',
                    enddate: '02/11/2014',
                    mark: false,
                    expanded: true,
                    children: [
                        {
                            year: 2014,
                            week: 33,
                            startdate: '03/11/2014',
                            enddate: '04/11/2014',
                            mark: false,
                            leaf: true
                        },
                        {
                            year: 2014,
                            week: 33,
                            startdate: '05/11/2014',
                            enddate: '06/11/2014',
                            mark: false,
                            leaf: true
                        },
                        {
                            year: 2014,
                            week: 33,
                            startdate: '07/11/2014',
                            enddate: '08/11/2014',
                            mark: false,
                            leaf: true
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    year: 2014,
                    week: 34,
                    startdate: '09/11/2014',
                    enddate: '10/11/2014',
                    expanded: false,
                    mark: false,
                    children: [
                        {
                            year: '2014',
                            week: 34,
                            startdate: '11/11/2014',
                            enddate: '12/11/2014',
                            mark: false,
                            leaf: true
                        },
                        {
                            year: 2014,
                            week: 34,
                            startdate: '13/11/2014',
                            enddate: '14/11/2014',
                            mark: false,
                            leaf: true
                        },
                        {
                            year: 2014,
                            week: 34,
                            startdate: '15/11/2014',
                            enddate: '16/11/2014',
                            mark: false,
                            leaf: true
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    year: 2014,
                    week: 35,
                    startdate: '17/11/2014',
                    enddate: '18/11/2014',
                    mark: false,
                    expanded: false,
                    children: [
                        {
                            year: 2014,
                            week: 35,
                            startdate: '19/11/2014',
                            enddate: '20/11/2014',
                            mark: false,
                            leaf: true
                        },
                        {
                            year: 2014,
                            week: 35,
                            startdate: '21/11/2014',
                            enddate: '22/11/2014',
                            mark: false,
                            leaf: true
                        },
                        {
                            year: 2014,
                            week: 35,
                            startdate: '23/11/2014',
                            enddate: '24/11/2014',
                            mark: false,
                            leaf: true
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    year: 2014,
                    week: 36,
                    startdate: '17/11/2014',
                    enddate: '18/11/2014',
                    mark: false,
                    expanded: false,
                    children: [
                        {
                            year: 2014,
                            week: 36,
                            startdate: '19/11/2014',
                            enddate: '20/11/2014',
                            mark: false,
                            leaf: true
                        },
                        {
                            year: 2014,
                            week: 36,
                            startdate: '21/11/2014',
                            enddate: '22/11/2014',
                            mark: false,
                            leaf: true
                        },
                        {
                            year: 2014,
                            week: 36,
                            startdate: '23/11/2014',
                            enddate: '24/11/2014',
                            mark: false,
                            leaf: true
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    year: 2014,
                    week: 37,
                    startdate: '17/11/2014',
                    enddate: '18/11/2014',
                    mark: false,
                    expanded: false,
                    children: [
                        {
                            year: 2014,
                            week: 37,
                            startdate: '19/11/2014',
                            enddate: '20/11/2014',
                            mark: false,
                            leaf: true
                        },
                        {
                            year: 2014,
                            week: 37,
                            startdate: '21/11/2014',
                            enddate: '22/11/2014',
                            mark: false,
                            leaf: true
                        },
                        {
                            year: 2014,
                            week: 37,
                            startdate: '23/11/2014',
                            enddate: '24/11/2014',
                            mark: false,
                            leaf: true
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    year: 2014,
                    week: 37,
                    startdate: '17/11/2014',
                    enddate: '18/11/2014',
                    mark: false,
                    expanded: false,
                    children: [
                        {
                            year: 2014,
                            week: 37,
                            startdate: '19/11/2014',
                            enddate: '20/11/2014',
                            mark: false,
                            leaf: true
                        },
                        {
                            year: 2014,
                            week: 37,
                            startdate: '21/11/2014',
                            enddate: '22/11/2014',
                            mark: false,
                            leaf: true
                        },
                        {
                            year: 2014,
                            week: 37,
                            startdate: '23/11/2014',
                            enddate: '24/11/2014',
                            mark: false,
                            leaf: true
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of removing the store values after render  and again loading the store on button click ,could you please try the below once which i came accross in a post,

Just define an empty expanded root with no children initially, and then you can load the store whenever you want:

```
 Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    model: '...',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data'
    },
    api: {
        read : 'some url'
    }
    folderSort: true,
    rootVisible: false,
    root: {expanded: true, text: "", "data": []} // <- Inline root
});
```

After an explicit .load the inline root is overwritten.
    Hope this helps you.

Comment: Cannot do that getting "Ext.data.proxy.Server.buildUrl(): You are using a ServerProxy but have not supplied it with a url."

Comment: Ok tweak your answer a bit. We must not use the proxy in the store definition, else will give error as i told above.  Cab done by store.load({url:'myurl'});. This worked for me :)